# JMeter Getting Parameters From ResponseParameters To Generate New Request

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to use Jmeter to test a website that uses Servlet+Struts+WebSphereCommerce Technology. I would like to be able to generate Request according to previous response.

I use View Results Tree after html request in order to inspect response of the previous call but i do not see the parameters (responseProperties) i set in response. instead i just see piece of .js code, html code or images.

how to gather response properties?

finally i would like to be able to use such properties to create the following request.

Comment: JMeter makes HTTP requests to web sites. You'll get back whatever the web app renders, e.g., JavaScript, CSS, and HTML. You have to pull data from the DOM, and this is covered in the JMeter docs.

Comment: Please confirm do you see the correct response it you try to access the same html request via browser?

Comment: Hi I confirm, the response was actually to long and i had to print it into a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter provides [Beanshell scripting](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as extension mechanism so you can add a [Beanshell Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child to your HTTP Request and refer to response properties as follows:

```
String responseCode = prev.getResponseCode();
String responseHeaders = prev.getResponseHeaders();
String responseMessage = prev.getResponseMessage();
String responseData = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
```

Where `prev` is a shor-hand for previous [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

If you want to use a part of response in next request (this is called "correlation") JMeter provides other Post Processors which can extract data from response and store it into JMeter Variables for later re-use such as:

- [Regular Expressions Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

etc.

Hope this helps.